# Displaying this symbol ╠ instead of desired characters

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

Here is a snippet of some code. Instead of displaying the characters I am checking for, ╠ is displayed.

```
while (c!= EOF)
{
    c = getc(fp);
    if (c==32 || c==33 || (c>=97 && c<=122) || c==35)
    j++;
    if(j==clns){
    i++;
    j=0;
    mA[i][j]=c;
    }

}


for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        printf("%c", mA[i][j]);
    }
    printf("%c\n", mA[i][j]);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Comment: That 'symbol' cannot fit into a single `char` most likely, as it is unicode.

Comment: please post full code. do you initialize `mA` ?

Comment: I haven't seen that character for years!!  Used to be one of the characters you used to create text-based windows in DOS, before MS Windows hit the scene.  It certainly used to fit in a `char`, as it was part of the Extended ASCII set (128-255).  But perhaps it has been moved somewhere else now, since text-windowing is a lost art.

Comment: Ahh here we go...  Anyone who was anyone used to have a printout of [this image](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/Images/ascii2.gif) (or similar) on hand at all times.  If I type Alt-204 (on the numeric keypad), I still get a `╠`.  Looks like the standard is still alive and kicking.

Comment: ╠ is 0xCC in codepage 437, and [MSVC fills 0xCC to uninitialized memory to help debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714). That means you've accessed uninitialized memory. You can find tons of questions about ╠ and 0xCC here on SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only ever writing to `mA[i][0]`:

```
if(j==clns){
    i++;
    j=0;
    mA[i][j]=c;
}
```

so you are printing random garbage that happened to be in the array. Move the assignment out of the `if`.